# Sparql query to find football clubs in Spain and their stadiums

Tags: sql, sparql, rdf, dbpedia

I would like to retrieve football clubs in Spain and their stadiums.Below is the query that I have written for retrieving clubs , but can not retrieve with  appropriate stadiums.Here is my code

```
    SELECT ?clubs WHERE
 {
    ?clubs dct:subject dbc:Football_clubs_in_Spain.

 }
```

If possible could you help me with this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried your query and it seems that `dct:subject dbc:Football_clubs_in_Spain` is not the best choice, because it's not consistently stated about Spanish soccer clubs (a prominent example - [FC Barcelona](http://dbpedia.org/resource/FC_Barcelona)). A better choice would be to select `?club` by type SoccerClub.

Unfortunately, again with Barcelona as example, you may find that a club's description lacks general geographic information. For Barcelona you don't get a general statement saying that it's a Spanish team. Hence I decided to limit by the location of the teams' grounds.

Here's the query I came up with:

```
SELECT ?club ?grounds WHERE
{
    # select a SoccerClub and it's grounds
    ?club a dbo:SoccerClub ;
          dbo:ground ?grounds . 

    # limit only to grounds which are in Spain
    ?grounds dbo:location dbr:Spain.
}
```

It returns 68 clubs. Not perfect and you probably could get more if you find other reliable patterns in the data.